# Tab Stop not working for the section Tab page in Tab control C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I have a C# application where I am using Tab Control with two Tab Pages. I have a button on first Tab Page and on buttonclick, I remove the first Tab Page and display the second Tab Page. My problem is when I get on the second Tab Page, my control gets stuck on the Tab Page `Text` instead of the textbox inside the tab. I have set the Tab Stop property of the Tab Control to `False`, and it is working fine for the first Tab Page but not for second Tab Page. I have also set the Tab Index property correctly.

Please help me find the issue here.
Code for hiding Tab Pages:

```
btnAppend.Click += delegate 
        { 
            AppendEvent?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            tbcntrl1.TabPages.Remove(tbpglist);
            tbcntrl1.TabPages.Add(tbpgform);
            tbpgform.Text = "Append";
            tbcntrl1.TabStop = false;

        };
```

I am attaching a few screenshots for reference.
[image]
[image]

First Tab page where control on landing on append button
[image]

Second tab page where it should have been on Textbox of Name.
[image]

---

**Edit:**
This line in the `btnAppend.Click` code worked for some reason, but still doesn't explain why `Tab Stop = false` is not working:

```
this.SelectNextControl(tbcntrl1, true, true, true, true);
```

Comment: You're not hiding tabPage, but deleting it. and you set the tabPage Text to "Append":
`tbpgform.Text = "Append";`

Comment: @tretom That is the only way I found to hide and show tabs, and yes i am setting the tabpage Text. Is that relevant to the control issue?

Comment: please double check it, but I think, hiding a tabpage can be made with: `tabControl.TabPages[0].Visible = false;`

but about your real question: have you tried to set the Focus to the textbox? `textBoxName.Focus();`
By the end of your delegate the textbox must already exist